# Figure out where my nodejs thread is hanging?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I have a node server running. Once in a while, the main thread hangs and goes to 100% CPU usage. The thread is totally hung and not processing any further events whatsoever.

Unfortunately, because of this, even attaching the node debugger is not useful since the thread is hung somewhere (I ran node's debugger and attached to the stalled process but [for example] 'pause' or 'bt' does not return).

How can I figure out where it is hanging? Is it possible to have node keep track of the current closure stack so that I can get access to it retrospectively when the bug occurs again?

Answer (score 1):

One low-level method of checking is to use a utility like strace. You can use it like: `strace -p <node pid>`. This will only show syscalls however, so if your program is in some kind of infinite loop that is not making any syscalls (like performing I/O) you won't see any output.

You might also try using [llnode](https://github.com/nodejs/llnode) to attach to the live process to get a more node-friendly interface to the node process (compared to using gdb).

As far as seeing what handles/requests are active in the node process, there are a couple of "*private*" (underscore-prefixed) methods available if you are feeling adventurous: `process._getActiveHandles()` and `process._getActiveRequests()`. You might use those functions in conjunction with a module like [`blocked`](https://github.com/tj/node-blocked) which helps detect when the event loop is executing slower than whatever threshold you want.

Comment: I appreciate the answer with some very useful suggestions. Unfortunately, none of these are able to address the crux of the question (how to determine the closure stack where node is hung in the main thread). Nevertheless I will explore your suggestions to see if they can help. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode helps make use of _getActiveHandles